# `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have specified the following routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, except: [:show]
  get 'posts/*id(/:permalink)', to: 'posts#show', as: :post
end
```

When I run the application I get this error:

```
`add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'post'  (ArgumentError)
```

But when I add `:update` and `:destroy` to the exception list for the purpose of debugging I don't get any error:

```
resources :posts, except: [:show, :update, :destroy]
```

In the first case, why the paths of `:update` and `:destroy` overlap with the path of `:show` while they are using different http verbs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First, the source of your error is that `resources :posts` is probably creating a named route for `post_path`. So, on the next line when you declare `get 'posts/*id(/:permalink)', to: 'posts#show', as: :post`, the `as: :post` attribute is trying  to create a path called `post_path`, which already exists as the error indicates.

Secondly, why do you want `posts#show` to handle both GET and POST requests? I can't think of a reason why this would be a good thing. It may also present some security issues depending on what the `show` action is actually doing.

Comment: How `resources :posts` creates `post_path` while I added `, except: [:show]`?   
I didn't want `posts#show` to handle both GET and POST requests. I just said that why when I add `:update` and `:destroy` to the exception list I don't get any errors.